# How to get phone on in customer form edit(Account setting) Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, edit

I have added a phone no text box in Customer Account edit form(Account Edit).

> Block file
>   \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit

The issue is, I am not able to get the phone no to get it after the user saved it.

For dob(date of birth)

```
 <?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob') ?>

 <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
       <?= $_dob->setDate($block->getCustomer()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
 <?php endif ?>
```

For Telephone, I am not able to get phone no.

```
 <?php $_telephone = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Telephone') ?>

 <?php if ($_telephone->isEnabled()): ?>
       <?= $_telephone->setTelephone($block->getCustomer()->getTelephone())->toHtml() ?>
 <?php endif ?>
```

as error is

```
Method 'getTelephone' not found in Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface more...
```

How can I get Customer telephone no, from this interface 
`Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface`

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to get the `getTelephone()` on `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface` because `Telephone` is part of **`customer address`** `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface`  object not for **`customer`** object.

So If you want the `Telephone` then you need to get the address object of the customer then you can get the `Telephone` value

i.e

`$block->getAddress()->getTelephone()`

Comment: I get this error $block->getAddress()->getTelephone(), because block \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit has so such function getAddress()

Comment: correct, because each address has own telephone number so you need to first select the address then you can get the telephone , but I think you know the reason error which you are getting :) @summu

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in order to get default phont number in the edit form...

```
$customer = $block->getCustomer();
$defaultBillingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
$addressesArr = $customer->getAddresses();
$defaultShippingAddress = $addressesArr[$defaultBillingAddressId - 1];
echo $defaultShippingAddress->getTelephone();
```

The problem is that my phone number doesn't saved when submit the form.